# How to center different content in div?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have a `div` with a label next to it, like this:
[image]

This is how my `html` in `Vue.js` looks like:

```
    <div style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
      <input
        id="newsletterRegister"
        type="checkbox"
        name="newsletterRegister"
        style="width: 30px"
      />
      <label for="newsletterRegister">
        Do you want to receive email promotions?
      </label>
    </div>
```

I have no idea how to center the `label` next to the `checkbox`. I have tried a lot of things, but it doesn't seem to be working. Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `flexbox`

```css
.center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-bottom: 15px" class="center">
  <input id="newsletterRegister" type="checkbox" name="newsletterRegister" style="width: 30px" />
  <label for="newsletterRegister">
        Do you want to receive email promotions?
      </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just put the `display: flex; align-items: center;` in the div style, it'll do the job

```html
  <div style="margin-bottom: 15px; display: flex; align-items: center;">
      <input
        id="newsletterRegister"
        type="checkbox"
        name="newsletterRegister"
        style="width: 30px"
      />
      <label for="newsletterRegister">
        Do you want to receive email promotions?
      </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'vertical-align' like this:

```html
<div style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
      <input
        id="newsletterRegister"
        type="checkbox"
        name="newsletterRegister"
        style="width: 30px; vertical-align:bottom;"
      />
      <label for="newsletterRegister">
        Do you want to receive email promotions?
      </label>
    </div>
```

Or alternatively You could set labels (`.newsletterRegister`) `line-height` style to the same as checkbox height is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex;` and `justify-content:center;` to align the items horizontally and `align-items: center` to align items vertically. Try running the snippet if this works for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
   <div style="margin-bottom: 15px; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
    <input
     id="newsletterRegister"
     type="checkbox"
     name="newsletterRegister"
     style="width: 30px"
    />
    <label for="newsletterRegister">
     Do you want to receive email promotions?
    </label>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the center tag

It is very old-fashioned but it works.

Comment: You should not do this, as `<center>` is deprecated. You can read this here: [<center>: The Centered Text element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)

Comment: Okay thanks! I thought this might work